# Find the antiderivative of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

> Let $S= \{0\} \cup \{ \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ and define $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as $f(x)= \min \{ |x-t| : t \in S \}$
>   a) Prove that $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |x-y|$ for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$
>   b) Find the antiderivatives of $f$

I obtained the following form for the function:
$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
-x, \quad &x \leq 0 \\
x-\frac{1}{n+1}, \quad &\frac{1}{n+1} \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n}) \\
\frac{1}{n}-x, \quad  &\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n}) < x < \frac{1}{n} \\
x-1, \quad &x \geq 1
\end{cases}$$

I then tried to prove the inequality from a) considering many cases for $x$ and $y$, but there are many possibilities. For the antiderivatives, I tried to combine the antiderivatives for each of the 4 branches of the function, but again, the calculations are messy.

Comment: Note that for any set $A$, the function $\min(\cdot, A)$ is 1-Lipschitz: using triangle inequality for some $a$ and then taking a bound, the common way is to prove that $\min(x,A) \le \min(y,A)+|x-y|$, and $\min(y,A) \le \min(x,A)+|y-x|$. Snake707 gave a detailed proof below

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

1. For any $\epsilon > 0$ there is $s'\in S$ such that $|x-s'| \leq f(x) + \epsilon$. We know that $f(y) \leq |y-s'| = |y-x+x-s'|\leq |y-x|+f(x)+\epsilon$. Since this holds for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have $f(y) \leq f(x) + |y-x|$.
2. For any $\delta > 0$ there is $t'\in S$ such that $|y-t'| \leq f(y) + \delta$. Analogously, $f(x) \leq |x-t'| = |x-y+y-t'|\leq |x-y|+ f(y) + \delta$. Since this holds for any $\delta > 0$ we have $f(x)\leq f(y) + |y-x|$.
3. Thus we have
   $$\begin{equation}
   f(x)-f(y) \leq |x-y|\\
   f(y)-f(x) \leq |y-x|.
   \end{equation}$$
   Thus $|f(y)-f(x)|\leq |y-x|$.

No let $S$ be defined as in your example and you are done.

Comment: Thank you! How about the antiderivative?

Comment: Your antiderivative is fine (don't forget $+C$ ;-) ).

Comment: Oh, but I don't have a closed form for it